# Java error when trying to run firebase emulators

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-tools

I am trying to run the firebase emulators using

```
firebase emulators:start
```

however this is the error I get

> Error: Could not spawn `java -version`. Please make sure Java is installed and on your system PATH.

I then run

```
npm install java
```

I cannot install java.

Comment: What is the reason you can't install Java? The npm java is not the Java SDK IIUC, you may need to install the Java SDK before running `npm install java`.

Comment: Do you have Java installed on your system? The npm package `java` is just a `Bridge API to connect with existing Java APIs` as the npm description says. You need the Java binaries on your system as well.

It might be, that Java is not installed or the executable is not accessible since the PATH environment variable ([see explanation here](https://superuser.com/a/284351) does not point to the folder containing the executable.

Comment: Pascal is correct. That fixed my error.

Answer (score -1):

try this command line

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

then run the command

```
firebase emulators:start
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I get `The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.`